# Black Screen ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, login-screen

This is duplicate. But the older questions were not answered. So, you can count that this a reminder question (if no answer, I will set bounty).

I have Ubuntu 15.04. Sometimes, when I open the laptop and log-in, the display is filled with black screen. But everything is running (I can even enter to the tty by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (tty mode is displayed) and exit), only the display is not working. So, I need to reboot.
After reboot, the system works normally.

I need cause of this problem alongside answer. So, please do not hesitate to write detailed. Any help will be much appreciated.

My tries: updated NVIDIA drivers, used Nouveau display drivers. And I concluded that this not driver fault.

**1st Update**: I use `lightdm-gtk-greeter`.

**2nd Update**: I installed deb file from the link and this is the output from `unity-reset`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity-reset", line 67, in <module>
    subprocess.call("unity")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think full download is needed... I will try to download it in 1-2 days then update the results.

**3rd Update**: Reinstalling `lightdm-gtk-greeter` did not work. I get black screen after second close-open...

**4th Update**:

```
$ find /usr/sbin/ -name "*dm"
/usr/sbin/lightdm

$ ps ax | grep dm
846 ?        SLsl   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
853 tty7      Ssl+   1:57 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
1032 ?        Sl     0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
2347 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dm
```

**5th Update**:
I have noticed that when I close laptop, it sometimes suspends unusually longer and only after that this problem occurs.

Comment: I have same problem, when I resume from suspend. One way to fix this is to not to use NVIDIA or Nouveau drivers and use Intel's Open Source Drivers

Comment: I think, Intel's Open Source Drivers are intended for mobile devices.

Comment: I dont think so, why would you think that? Intel's Open source **graphics** drivers are made for desktop so that includes PC and laptop

Comment: I will try it then

Comment: [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) is the link for automatic installer, dont forget to [switch from Nvidia to Intel drivers](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html) before you install it. Also dont forget that it solves the problem of getting black screen after resuming from suspend (as mentioned in my first comment)

Comment: Like "edward torvalds"  I too  have this problem sometimes, when resuming from suspend, I have found out that its the login screen that's not showing - When entering the pasword and pressing Enter - the normal background reapers for work duty, why only sometimes is a mystery, and do not play with the mouse on the black screen, that will remove the focus from the login box!!

Comment: Thank you very much @edward torvalds. But Intel drivers caused overheating on my computer. So the solution that you have provided does not suit me. Then I did clean install of Ubuntu 15.04, but it did not help too...

Comment: @Olimjon, Could you post output of `find /usr/sbin/ -name "*dm"` and `ps ax | grep dm`

Comment: Is this the same bug as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1268211?

Comment: No , it occurs sometimes, not always.

Comment: I have a similar issue, about 10% of the time, I get a black screen when resuming from suspend. I usually switch to tty1 and kill the locking program. It gets respawned, and asks for my password after I switch back to tty7. But I have other graphics issues (10s-freezes, once every 2 hours) so it might be unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you assume that it is not a graphics drivers issue ... trying this solution might be a chance to get your problem solved - it worked in many similar cases ... first remove the drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
enter user name and password ... execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Identify the graphics adapter ... execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

For GEFORCE 400 - 700 I recommend to install the NVIDIA drivers version 352.
For GEFORCE 800 - 900 I recommend to install the NVIDIA drivers version 358.

**Installation instructions for NVIDIA drivers version 352 :**

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
enter user name and password ... execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

**Installation instructions for NVIDIA drivers version 358 :**

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
enter user name and password ... execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Note :

Generally you should use the NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories. But when there are problems with the drivers ... then you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA. This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on new NVIDIA adapters.

Answer (score -2):

I was also facing the same Display issue today with Ubuntu 15.04 and I did following steps through the *terminal*:

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"


sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo restart gdm
```

Issue has been fixed Now.

Comment: `gdm` ? the person said just Ubuntu, so he might be using `lightdm`

Comment: I think it is because mentioned "I have Ubuntu 15.04. Sometimes_"

Comment: @RameshChand I think you miss read that sentence, it is not " I have Ubuntu 15.04. Sometimes" It is two sentences "I have Ubuntu 15.04." then "Sometimes, when I open..." Edwards point is, on Unity `gdm` won't work, change it for `lightdm` for Unity, so that it answers this question..

Comment: Ok Correct I missed it is "I have Ubuntu 15.04".

Comment: @RameshChand You still did not change you answer to reflect the fact OP has `lightdm` not `gdm`, you may be right here, but as it stands, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --reset-icon &disown
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Have you tried this: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop & startx

Comment: I do not have ubuntu-desktop. I have XFCE.

Comment: Try this: sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu & startx